# Playbook runs more times than the provided inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

My playbook, even though I only have one server in my inventory, runs twice.

```
[me@server ansible_scripts]$ sudo -u userA ansible-playbook ssl_playbook.yml -i inventories/staging ssl_playbook.yml --private-key=/path/to/key.key --u userB

PLAY [custom_group] ***********************************************************

TASK [Copy and backup SSL related files] ***************************************
ok: [server.mydomain.com] => (item=ssl_chain.crt)
ok: [server.mydomain.com] => (item=ssl.crt)
ok: [server.mydomain.com] => (item=ssl.key)

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
server.mydomain.com : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0

PLAY [custom_group] ***********************************************************

TASK [Copy and backup SSL related files] ***************************************
ok: [server.mydomain.com] => (item=ssl_chain.crt)
ok: [server.mydomain.com] => (item=ssl.crt)
ok: [server.mydomain.com] => (item=ssl.key)

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
server.mydomain.com : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

`inventories/staging/hosts`:

```
[custom_group]
server.mydomain.com
```

`ssl-playbook.yml`:

```
- hosts: custom_group
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: Copy and backup SSL related files
    copy: 
      src: /u01/sslcert/{{item}}
      dest: /u01/etc/httpd/{{item}}
      backup: true
      force: true
      mode: "u=rwx,g=,o="
    with_items: '{{ssl_certificate_files}}'
    become: true
    become_user: apache

  handlers:
  - name: restart apache
    service: name=httpd state
```

`inventories/staging/group_vars`:

```
ssl_certificate_files:
  - ssl_chain.crt
  - ssl.crt
  - ssl.key
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove duplicate entry `ssl_playbook.yml` from your command.

Comment: Sigh. Been looking at this for hours... Thanks!